# Missing toolbars in WinEdt 11

Tags: editors, winedt

I use WinEdt 11. The toolbar is as in the first picture, but I want it to be like the second picture, because in the first I even have no (run/compile) PDFTEX menu!

[image]

Comment: I had the same issue. I tried multiple things and also to "rebuild default".
In order to solve the problem I had to uninstall and reinstall WinEdt.

Answer (score 1):

I am using WinEdt 10, and I can change toolbar styles in `Options->Toolbar` menu item. I guess WinEdt 11 doesn't change it.

[image]

Comment: Dear friend, Thanks a lot, but I used the toolbar and unfortunately, it did not change anything. I tried all options, but they did not work.

Comment: @JohnGreen Have you tried to restart WinEdt? If the menu items have no effects in WinEdt 11, you should report it as a bug.

Comment: Ok. Thanks a lot.